# Restore data on pod deletion in hashi vault

Tags: local-storage, hashicorp-vault, helm3, kubernetes-pvc, vault

How we can restore the data(secrets,policy,configurations) when a pod vault-0 is deleted from the vault namespace in helm based deployment.
We have tried by configuring the server datatstorage mountpath.

```
"server": map[string]interface{}{
        "dataStorage": map[string]interface{}{
            "mountPath": "/data/local-pv1",
        },
```

This configuration creates a pvc which is bound to a local-storage PV,

```
PV: local-pv-fb1e3919         10Gi       RWO            Delete           Bound         vault/data-vault-0                     local-storage            3h25m

PVC: data-vault-0   Bound    local-pv-fb1e3919   10Gi       RWO            local-storage   125m
```

Now if we are deleting the pod, the pod comes back but we are loosing all the data and vault goes back to **uninitialized** state. However the pv and pvc was not deleted when pod was deleted manually.
Not sure why data is not restored from pv and pvc, are we missing some more configurations.'

Comment: why not persistent storage with some db?

Comment: btw can you post `kubectl describe pvc pvc-name`